# Cannot Import products - No date part in '' found. error

Tags: magento-1.9, import

all of a sudden we cannot import products and are getting this message

```
No date part in '' found.
```

after checking the error logs this is getting thrown up multiple times

```
2014-08-26T19:31:33+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: DDL statements are not allowed in transactions  in /home/our-site/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 408
```

any idea why this is happening or how to fix it?  We haven't installed anything new recently.  We are using magento 1.9  thanks for the help

Comment: This error is returned when you create new Zend_Date() with argument equal to empty string ( "" ) instead of null to get current date. This class try to parse any string you passed to get info about data - and this error says, that it didn't found anything that can be a date in '' string :)

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same error in my Magento CE 1.9.0.1 When I import products. Not having AFAK any impact on the site.

> ERR (3): User Error: DDL statements are not allowed in transactions  in /lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 408

Found several references (including magento team) to comment out the trigger at:

/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

```
/**
 * Check transaction level in case of DDL query
 *
 * @param string|Zend_Db_Select $sql
 * @throws Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception
 */
protected function _checkDdlTransaction($sql)
{
    if (is_string($sql) && $this->getTransactionLevel() > 0) {
        $startSql = strtolower(substr(ltrim($sql), 0, 3));
        if (in_array($startSql, $this->_ddlRoutines)
            && (preg_match($this->_tempRoutines, $sql) !== 1)
        ) {
            // trigger_error(Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::ERROR_DDL_MESSAGE, E_USER_ERROR); < COMMENT OUT THE TRIGGER
        }
    }
}
```

A deeper explanation of the DDL statements error thrown can be found at http://zaclee.net/magento/custom-module-setup-createentitytables-method-fails.

However, the "No date part in" have never seen... you could start searching here:

/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php

```
    // split number parts
    $split = false;
    preg_match_all('/\d+/u', $number, $splitted);

    if (count($splitted[0]) == 0) {
        iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', $oenc);
        #require_once 'Zend/Locale/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Locale_Exception("No date part in '$date' found.");
    }
    if (count($splitted[0]) == 1) {
        $split = 0;
    }
```